# express-typescript-react: Send a json response after sending the view from the same request

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, express, webpack

Following is my code for a simple express-server written in typescript.

```
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import path from 'path';
import fs from 'fs';
import { DISTDIR } from './shared/constants';
import LoginController from './controllers/login';
// import * as test from '../../helpers/util';

function name() {
  return {
    name: 'Amaan'
  };
}
class App {
  public express: express.Application;

  constructor() {
    this.express = express();
    this.middleware();
    this.routes();
  }
  private middleware(): void {
    this.express.use(function(req, res, next) {
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
      res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', '*');
      next();
    });
    this.express.use(bodyParser.json());
    this.express.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  }
  private routes(): void {
    this.express.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.sendFile(path.join(projectDir, 'dist', 'index.html'));
    });
  }
}
export default new App().express;
```

As you can see here, I am sending back the `index.html` which contains my React code.

```
this.express.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(projectDir, 'dist', 'index.html'));
});
```

Now I am facing a problem where I need to send a response from any API in that request as well. Something like this:

```
function name() {
  return {
    name: 'Amaan'
  };
}

private routes(): void {
  this.express.get('/', function(_, res) {
  res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/html');
  fs.readFile(path.resolve(DISTDIR, 'index.html'), null, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(404);
      res.write('Not found');
    } else {
      res.write(data);
    }
    res.setHeader('Content-type', 'text/json');
    res.send(name());
    res.end();
  });
});
```

This is giving me a `'Can\'t set headers after they are sent.'` error.

Please tell me, how I can send a json response along with the view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can send json after sending an HTML file in one response. You can make a React component to send another request to fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

One response for one request. If you need something on initialization of app, use the onLoad function to make another request.

Answer (score 0):

Did some research and discovered that this sort of arrangement is very tightly coupled and yes, we can't send more than one response per request. Needless to say, I used `webpack-dev-server` to fire up the frontend and removed the middleware from the express code.